# Is auto-iso affected by exposure compensation in manual (M) mode on nikon d7000?

Tags: nikon, exposure, auto-iso

When we set the camera to M mode the exposure compensation (e.g. +2EV) does not change the aperture and shutter because we are in fully manual mode. If we set auto iso the iso however changes according to the current light metering.
I'm wondering whether auto-iso affected by exposure compensation in manual (M) mode on nikon d7000?

Comment: It is not on a Canon :-( -- this is a feature I would love to have.

Comment: Some higher end Canons have the option for *Auto ISO* to adjust for metering even in **Manual** shooting mode, but exposure compensation is not active. Most, if not all, current Canon DSLRs will allow Flash Exposure Compensation to be active when using E-TTL even in **Manual** shooting mode.

Comment: Pentax has a separate `TAv` mode, where shutter and aperture are manual but ISO is automatic. This leaves `M` to be fully manual.

Comment: TAv on a Pentax is the same as M on a Canon that allows Auto ISO to be enabled in M mode. If you select a specific ISO on the Canon, it is fully manual.

Comment: Just so odd to call it Manual mode when ISO is going on automatic.

Answer (score 2):

Exposure compensation basically effects the metering. Because the camera meters to 18% gray, exposure compensation is there to allow you to adjust the parameters used to meter to account for bright subjects or dark subjects, basically by allowing you to indicate that the scene is lighter or darker than the camera thinks.

So, in that aspect, this would effect the ISO chosen by the D7000 when in auto-iso mode in an otherwise manual selection. Obviously, fully manual selections of shutter, ISO, and aperture are unaffected by compensation selection, it just affects the meter's display.